# Tuleap - how install webdav plugin?

Tags: plugins, webdav, tuleap

I recently installed the webdav plugin, unfortunately it does not work.
I followed the instructions in the readme of the plugin, ie:

## "INSTALLATION

Option 1: if you access to webdav by "http [s] :/ / webdav.domain.tld"

```
 Under / etc / httpd / conf / httpd.conf:
 Add a virtual host to WebDAV domain name (before definition of "Project website hosts virtual alias" if any):
 <VirtualHost webdav.domain.tld:80>
     Include conf.d / php.conf
     DocumentRoot / usr / share / Codendi / plugins / webdav / www

     AliasMatch ^ / (. *) / Usr / share / Codendi / plugins / webdav / www / index.php

     <Directory /usr/share/codendi/plugins/webdav/www>
         Options Indexes MultiViews
         AllowOverride None
         Order allow, deny
         Allow from all
     </ Directory>
 </ VirtualHost>
```

Then plugin configuration:
webdav_base_uri = "/";
webdav_host = "webdav.domain.tld"

## CONFIGURATION

1. Go to PluginsAdministartion
2. Configure properties
3. Make the plugin available. "

For our configuration, we use :
Tuleap is on :
     project.domain.com on apache server on Centos 6.5
     Tuleap version 7.3
Webdav configuration :
     
     webdav_host = "files.project.domain.com"

however, if we want to access: http://files.project.domain.com, we obtained a beautiful 404, and in the apache logs: "File does not exist: / home / groups / files".
and https, it is transferred to tuleap ...

If someone have ideas, it will be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add it before the final Virtual host:

```
#
# Subversion virtual hosts alias
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName %sys_default_domain%
        ServerAlias svn.*. %sys_default_domain%
        Include conf.d/codendi_svnroot.conf
</VirtualHost>

... place it here ...    

#
# Project web site virtual hosts alias
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName %sys_default_domain%
    ServerAlias *.%sys_default_domain%
...
</VirtualHost>
```

Otherwise it will be catched by `*.%sys_default_domain%`